# Lync 2013 client escaping special characters

Tags: lync-2013

Our organisation recently rolled out Lync 2013.

Some people (myself included) are experiencing certain characters being escaped in a conversation but only for outbound messages.

For example, if I send the message

```
test, "test", <test>
```

it is sent as

```
test, &quot;test&quot;, &lt;test&gt;
```

Whereas for most other people it's

```
test, "test", <test>
```

sent as

```
test, "test", <test>
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before or know how to prevent it escaping the characters?